# What is the survest equivalent when running a mixed effects cox regression using coxme in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models, survival-analysis

I ran this mixed effects model

`survival<-coxme(Surv(tr_dur_a,ftr_2)~mod_muac+ drev_oedema_now_day0+danger_adm+tr_diet2+danger_adm + tr_daysec+hiv_stat+breast_feeding_adm+ sex_adm+mod_diar+diag_sepsis_adm+diag_lrti_pneumonia_adm +other_dx+ (1|site), data=survival1b)`

I would like the coxme equivalent of survest. My aim is to get survival probabilities

So I am aiming for something like:
`Csur <- survest(survival,newdata = Cnew, times=time)`

Comment: Can you add an example of your dataset? So we can try to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for response.  I am new to the site. Here is a link to a dummy dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TsYMU18YdkGJrrQwWoc38U-nRTSo9OW5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have clearly seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467243/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-event-probability-from-a-coxme-model since you posted this question in an answer location on that page. Why are you not paying attention to what was said there?

Comment: Thanks, as per the last but one response on that thread,  the proposed method has limitations and did not work for me after several attempts. The last response provides a possible solution but an example code is missing.